# Need to get normal text and superscript text as Display name for radproperty grid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Below is the code I have written in WPF

```
<telerik:RadPropertyGrid Margin="2" x:Name="ptLocation" FieldIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" SortAndGroupButtonsVisibility="Collapsed" IsGrouped="False" Item="{Binding Path=Selected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" SearchBoxVisibility="Collapsed" AutoGeneratePropertyDefinitions="False" LabelColumnWidth="120" DescriptionPanelVisibility="Collapsed"  >
                            <telerik:RadPropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
                                <telerik:PropertyDefinition x:Name="cmpAppClientNo" OrderIndex="0" Binding="{Binding Location.ApplicantClientNo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"   Description="Client No" DisplayName="Client No">
```

where displayname accepts only string but i want to write text block in that.

Comment: You can do this only if you override all template of PropertyGridPresenter... There is TextBlock with DisplayName binded to Text property. And why you need some extra TextBlock there?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I want to show superscript for every column label but Display name is taking only string but we can apply superscript for TextBlock or text only, i am not getting how to apply superscript for radpropertygrid column lable